# Log4j referring to external properties file in class path

Tags: log4j

I have a log4j.properties file

```
    log4j.appender.BigBrotherLog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.BigBrotherLog.File=${userprofile.broker.bigbrother.log4j.file.path}
    log4j.appender.BigBrotherLog.MaxFileSize=100MB
    log4j.appender.BigBrotherLog.MaxBackupIndex=10
    log4j.appender.BigBrotherLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.BigBrotherLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd} %d{HH:mm:ss} ALARM CRITICAL SITA ESB (SOAESB) [%-t] (%F:%L) %-5p %-c{1} %x- %m%n
    log4j.appender.BigBrotherLog.Threshold=FATAL
```

where I'm passing ${userprofile.broker.bigbrother.log4j.file.path} from a external properties file. But I want to have put this external properties file in the class path. How can I make it work? Thanks.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vertx/Nz5ERcyaEoA/MGHBPzvDCQAJ

Not taking credit for the solution, just posting a link.

Answer (score 7):

When you invoke the java command, pass in the system property `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:[path-to-your-external-file]`. The important part is the `file:`, otherwise log4j will only attempt to load from the class path and system resources.

You can also use `-Dlog4j.debug=true` to see where log4j has attempted to source it's configuration file from.